# Angularjs : I want to set a value to bind on my Checkbox if its untouched/unchecked

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a small problem here. How can i send a default value for a checkbox to its ng-model? for example i have this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.data" ng-value="yes" /> ready?
```

my Goal is to send "No" value if the checkbox is uncheck or untouch. thanks!

Comment: You could use `ng-true-value="'yes'"` & `ng-false-value="'no'"` but you have to set value explicitly to `ng-model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize `data.data` with your default value

Comment: hmm. i think this will work but is there no more solution for this? hehe thanks

Comment: @microprogramming well, that is the "correct" (idiomatic) solution for this. Angular is based on data binding, if you want your data to have a value by default then..give it a value ;-) Is there a problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data.data===false){
  data.data='No'
}
```

//do something

Also you can set default value with `ng-init` attribute